# MYSQL - specify seperator character when aggregating ( group_by )?

Tags: mysql

Some of my combined values have a comma in the textfield, is there a way I can specify the character with which to be concatenated by, instead of a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can find the full syntax

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

and the following example for GROUP_CONCAT

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) page explains this lucidly.

GROUP_CONCAT() function is used to concatenate column values into a single string. It is very useful if you would otherwise perform a lookup of many row and then concatenate them on the client end.

For example if you query:

```
mysql> SELECT Language FROM CountryLanguage WHERE CountryCode = 'THA';
```

It outputs:

```
Language
Chinese
Khmer
Kuy
Lao
```

To concatenate the values into a single string, you query:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Language) As Languages FROM CountryLanguage WHERE CountryCode = 'THA';
```

Then the output will be:

```
Languages
Chinese, Khmer, Kuy, Lao
```

You can also use some format of GROUP_CONCAT(). Like

- SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Language SEPARATOR ‘-’ )… It will use ‘-’ instead of ‘,’
- SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Language ORDER BY Language DESC )… To change the order and shorting output.

  thing to remember:

  GROUP_CONCAT() ignores NULL values.